# Script to display filtered game list based off of entered criteria? (Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AFTr_ji5iz8BJU9_OkZ1Xhfb9hg9ARAaRXfdVx2Y8pU/edit?usp=sharing

My apologies if my wording is confusing, as I am new to scripting and programming. I have a board game list with my friends that have the list of games we own, the estimated time it takes to play the game, and the min/max players required to play the game. I created a sheet where I would like to be able to input the number of players I have to play the game, and the amount of time we have to play. Then, when I click a button to run the script, it would display all of the available games that match my criteria. I have a formula that I was assisted in creating, but would like some more guidance on how to properly execute this action.

Above is a copy of the spreadsheet in question and the code is listed below:

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

function test() {
  var gamesThatFitCriteria = findGames(4,50);
}

function findGames(player, timeInMinutes) {
  var games = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
  games.shift(); //Remove first row
  games.shift(); //Remove second row

  var result = [];

  for (var i=0; i<games.length; i++) {
    var currentGame = games[i];

    var time = currentGame[2];
    var minPlayer = currentGame[3];
    var maxPlayer = currentGame[4];

    if (time<=timeInMinutes && player >= minPlayer && player <= maxPlayer) {
      //Eligible Game
      result.push(currentGame);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will provide you with a dialog to see all of the results.

```
function runThis() {
  var gamesThatFitCriteria = findGames(4,50);
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(gamesThatFitCriteria.join('<br />'));
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, "Games")
}

function findGames(player, timeInMinutes) {
  var games=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=games.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getRange(3,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn());
  var values=rg.getValues();
  var result = [];

  for (var i=0;i<values.length;i++) {
    var currentGame = values[i];

    var time = currentGame[2];
    var minPlayer = currentGame[3];
    var maxPlayer = currentGame[4];

    if (time<=timeInMinutes && player >= minPlayer && player <= maxPlayer) {
      result.push(currentGame);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

If you just want the game names:

```
function runThis() {
  var gamesThatFitCriteria = findGames(4,50);
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(gamesThatFitCriteria.join('<br />'));
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, "Games")
}

function findGames(player, timeInMinutes) {
  var games=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=games.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getRange(3,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn());
  var values=rg.getValues();
  var result = [];
  values.forEach(function(r){var name=r[0];var time=r[2];var minPlayer=r[3];var maxPlayer=r[4];if(time<=timeInMinutes && player >= minPlayer && player <= maxPlayer) {result.push(name);}});
  return result;
}
```

Here's an example of a complete custom dialog that lets you enter players and time and the select the desired game.  You can go to the getSelection() function and store the selection any where you wish with a setValue() function.

Just load this code into a .gs file and delete other functions with the same names.

```
function runOne() {
  var html='<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"><script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>';
  html+='<input type="text" id="player" placeholder="Players" /><br /><input type="text" id="time" placeholder="Time in minutes"><br /><input type="button" value="Get Games" onClick="getGames();" /><br /><div id="result"></div><div id="hidden" style="display:none;"><br /><select id="sel1"  class="control" style="width:150px;height:35px;margin:5px 0 5px 0;"><option value="" selected></option></select></div>';
  html+='<script>function getSelection(){var selection=document.getElementById("sel1").value;console.log("I am here");google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(r){google.script.host.close();}).getSelection(selection);}function getGames(){var players=document.getElementById("player").value;var minutes=document.getElementById("time").value;google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(rObj){updateSelect(rObj.games);document.getElementById("sel1").addEventListener("change", getSelection);$("#hidden").css("display","block");}).findGames(players,minutes);}function updateSelect(vA,id){var id=id ||"sel1";var select=document.getElementById(id);select.options.length = 0;for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){select.options[i]=new Option(vA[i],vA[i]);}}console.log("My Code");</script>';
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setWidth(800);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, "Find Games");
}

function findGames(player, timeInMinutes) {
  var games=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=games.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getRange(3,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn());
  var values=rg.getValues();
  var result = ['Select a game'];
  values.forEach(function(r){var name=r[0];var time=r[2];var minPlayer=r[3];var maxPlayer=r[4];if(time<=timeInMinutes && player >= minPlayer && player <= maxPlayer) {result.push(name);}});
  var rObj={games:result};
  return rObj;
}

function getSelection(selection) {
  var msg=Utilities.formatString('You have selected: %s',selection);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(msg);
  //you can put selection any where you want with setValue()
  return true;
}
```

> Run the runOne() function to launch the dialog.

Comment: Thank you! I assigned the runThis function to a button on the sheet. How do I connect cells to the script? For example, I would like to have a cell where I input how many players I have, and another cell to input how much time I have. (Maybe you have already done this for me, but I'm very new to scripts so I apologize)

Comment: Another question I had, is it possible to have this button on a separate sheet? It seems to only work when I assign the script to a button on the "Current" sheet.

Comment: I would just  run the function from a menu with something like `function onOpen() {SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('My Menu').addItem('Launch Get Games Dialog','runOne').addToUi();}`  If you have already created a menu for this project then just add it to that menu.